# how to use Jcrop with Laravel

Tags: laravel, jcrop, laravel-validation

I have watched this `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aflTCbGdzDc` tutorial for using jcrop, but it is for `Php`, when I'm using it with `Laravel`, the program stops at `Validation`, says `image filed is required`, like I haven't chosen an image, but I do have ! , and I'm seeing the image in the box . Note: when I push the upload button in crop modal, I get this error :
`POST http://localhost:8000/server/ctrl.php?fileapi155837244028211 404 (Not Found)` , it seems i need to set a post rout , but how ? i don't know . does anyone know how we should work with jcrop in laravel ?
here is my code :

```
<link href="{{asset('crop-userpic\style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="{{asset('crop-userpic\jcrop\jquery.jcrop.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <form method="post" action="{{route('testing')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <div class="container">
            <div id="userpic" class="userpic">
                <div class="js-preview userpic__preview"></div>
                <div class="btn btn-success js-fileapi-wrapper">
                    <div class="js-browse">
                        <span class="btn-txt">انتخاب عکس</span>
                        <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="js-upload" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="progress progress-success">
                            <div class="js-progress bar"></div>
                        </div>
                        <span class="btn-txt">در حال بارگذاری</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="popup" class="popup" style="display: none">
            <div class="popup__body">
                <div class="js-img"></div>
            </div>
            <div style="margin: 0 0 5px;text-align: center">
                <div class="js-upload btn btn_browse btn_browse_small">بارگذاری</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="sumbit" />
    </form>



    <script src="{{asset('crop-userpic\jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('crop-userpic\jquery.easing.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script>
        var FileAPI = {
            debug: true,
            media: true,
            staticPath: '{{asset('crop-userpic\FileAPI')}}'
        };
    </script>

    <script src="{{asset('crop-userpic\FileAPI\FileAPI.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('crop-userpic\FileAPI\FileAPI.exif.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('crop-userpic\jquery.Fileapi.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('crop-userpic\jcrop\jquery.Jcrop.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('crop-userpic\statics\jquery.modal.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{asset('crop-userpic\script.js')}}"></script>
```

and this is the image : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qgEmA9RlKy_eilZohCLajGmnVfqWSB9E

as you can see the image is in the box , but when i push submit , i get the validation error `image field is required` , like i don't have an image at all

please help me . i don't know what to do . and i love this Jcrop .